# Which Entities should be in my Pooling System?

Tags: architecture, design-patterns

Let's suppose that I'm designing a Tanks Battle Game, there will be a lot of projectiles and Tanks. Every Tank is composed with a Body, multiple Weapons such as Machine Guns, Missile Launchers, etc and different Shield Systems. I want to generate the Tanks at run-time and I will need to create and destroy them frequently. Should I add every type of Weapon, Shield, etc.. to my Pool System and recycle them when a Tank is destroyed, and later reuse them to assemble a new "Randomly" generated tank? Is this realistic? or should I just instantiate the Body, Weapons and Shields and don't use the Pool System for it? Do you have some tips for organize the Pool System?

I was looking for a advanced pooling system and I just got basic theory and examples. Any reference, suggestions, corrections or advice will be very grateful.

Comment: Don't use strings or lists for object pool, there are many awful tutorials on the internet. Use dictionaries and int for keys for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pooling is generally useful to eliminate the costs of creating and destroying objects of the same type over and over again, whatever those costs may be in your language.

So if you're going to create and destroy the tanks frequently, then yes, they may be a good candidate for pooling. If the creation and destruction of the tanks requires you to create and destroy related objects (such as the weapons on those tanks), they *also* may be a candidate for pooling.

Profiling your actual use case will help you find the places where pooling actually brings you significant wins versus places where it's just hedging against future performance issues that may not materialize.